# imagick distort keep perspective

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, distortion

I have developed a function to distort a PNG-logotype with dragpoints (using this function: http://codepen.io/fta/pen/ifnqH). The logotype itself is an image inside the div with dragpoints.

This logotype can later be generated as an image using PHP + Image Magick using the Imagick module. The logotype could be round, narrow or any kind of shape but the image is always in a 1:1 ratio (ex: 800x800) filled with transparency.

Now to the problem:

I always wan't the logotype to have the ratio 1:1 regarding on how wide or narrow the dragged area is (i don't wan't the logotype itself to be stretched). Although, the image itself can be distorted.

**The image on top illustrates how it works now, and the image in the bottom how i wan't it to work**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev0H8.jpg

Most importantly, this should work on the generated image using Image Magick + PHP. If it is possible to make it work on the client side using the dragpoints...that is a bonus.

I know how to get the real size of the logotype using `$image->trimImage(0);`

I should somehow be able to fill the edges of the image with extra transparency (x or y axis) to compensate for the stretch, but that is only so far i have come.

**This is my PHP-function to stretch or scale the logotype**

```
public function generate($file, $watermark, $offset = array()) {

        $file = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $file));
        $watermark = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $watermark));
        $width = (int)$this->config->get('config_image_popup_width');
        $height = (int)$this->config->get('config_image_popup_height');

        if (is_file($file) && is_file($watermark)) {

            $top = (int)$offset['top'];
            $left = (int)$offset['left'];
            $opacity = (float)$offset['opacity'];
            $new_width = (int)$offset['width'];
            $new_height = (int)$offset['height'];

            $topleft_y = (float)$offset['transform_topleft_y'];
            $topleft_x = (float)$offset['transform_topleft_x'];
            $topright_y = (float)$offset['transform_topright_y'];
            $topright_x = (float)$offset['transform_topright_x'];
            $bottomleft_y = (float)$offset['transform_bottomleft_y'];
            $bottomleft_x = (float)$offset['transform_bottomleft_x'];
            $bottomright_y = (float)$offset['transform_bottomright_y'];
            $bottomright_x = (float)$offset['transform_bottomright_x'];

            $image = new ImageMagick($file);
            $watermark = new ImageMagick($watermark);

            // Resize the product image
            $image->resize($width, $height);

            // Perspective has not changed, scale only
            if ($topleft_y == 0 && $topleft_x == 0 && $topright_y == 0 && $bottomleft_x == 0 && $topright_x == $bottomleft_y && $bottomleft_y == $bottomright_y && $bottomright_y == $bottomright_x) {
                $watermark->scale($new_width, $new_height);
            } else {
                $watermark->perspective($offset);
            }

            $watermark->opacity($opacity);
            $image->composite($watermark->get(), $left, $top);
            return $image->base64output(100);

        }
```